token exchange when trust is setup in reverse
This question is a fundamental question in trust setup in token exchange, unfortunately I do not have a clear understanding.
The scenario is as follows:
I have an application A which has IDP 1 as OAuth provider, and another application B with IDP 2 as Oauth provider.
IDP 1 has setup a trust relationship with IDP 2, so that a client can login to application A with IDP 2 credentials. Now there is need for application A calling APIs of application B. Application A receives access token from IDP 1 to get access to protected resources, I want to exchange the token issued by IDP 1 to a new token from IDP 2 by calling /token endpoint of IDP 2 so that this can be passed on behalf of user from Application A to application B in the API call.
The question is

since there is a trust setup where IDP 1 trust IDP 2 in a federated setup, is that enough to do a token exchange, or this is only a one way trust? Which mean IDP 2 also need to trust IDP 1 to be able to do a token exchange.
The call from application A to application B is system to system call where i want to use on behalf of flow as the API in application B expects user based access token to read the appropriate grant.
Is this the right approach? Wondering if the user logs out and access token is invalid in application A, still the token received in application B from IDP 2 might be valid.

